# Can't sort by date correctly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Instead ordering by day, is ordering by month.

I've tried `str_to_date` but doesn't have in spark sql, and tried to repeat `date_format` in `order by` with no success

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.sql("""
  SELECT TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ttr.created_at, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS TIMESTAMP)) AS data from dl_wallet.tb_transaction as ttr order by data desc """
).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're formatting the date as strings, sort is done by string order. One solution is to change the format so that year comes first, then month, then day. A better way is to order by the Date column (ttr.created_at) and not the formatted string.

Comment: Alright keep the format, but change your sort to `ORDER BY ttr.created_at`